# JQuery random input placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

How can i set random placeholder text from array of strings in jquery after document is loaded?
Now i have just "hardcoded" the setting for placeholder? But how to do it dynamically?

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $(document).ready(function () {
    var list = new Array();
    list.push("1");
    list.push("2");
        $('#search').attr("placeholder","placeholder text");
    });
});
```

Just how one time see 1, other 2...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  var list = [...],
      r = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  $('#search').prop('placeholder',list[r]);
});
```

that would use any of the possibilities within `list` and assign the placeholder a new random value from it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cxy8S/)